# Extending react-native-paper Button and Text components in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-paper

I was trying to make a reusable component using react-native-paper

the problem comes when I try to use extends a type from the package

```
import React from 'react';

import {Button, Text} from 'react-native-paper';

export type ButtonProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>;

type CustomButtonProps = ButtonProps & {
title: string;
};

export const ButtonPaper: React.FC<CustomButtonProps> = ({title, ...props}) => {
return (
<Button mode="contained" {...props}>
  welcome
</Button>
);
};
```

everything is fine so far but when I try to use the component on the screen, typescript gives me that error

[image]

any solution for that?

Comment: i think you can remove ButtonProps from CustomButtonProps

Comment: actually, the CustomButtonProps is needed because I need all the props of the button to pass it later to the component

Comment: can you try that by making into an interface with extends. something like this `interface CustomButtonProps  extends  ButtonProps  {}`

Comment: offtopic: couldt someone explain these pattern? i see this first `time.const ButtonPaper: React.FC<CustomButtonProps>`

Comment: @RahmanHaroon interface can't extend type as you know ), even I would have a TS error inside the component but I can ignore it if it works fine on the screen )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend it as shown below

Create a file `ButtonPaper.tsx`

```js
// Packages Imports
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native-paper";

// Type for CustomButton
export type CustomButtonProps = {
  title: string;
} & React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>;

// function component for CustomButton
const ButtonPaper: React.FC<CustomButtonProps> = ({ title, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Button mode="contained" {...props}>
      {title}
    </Button>
  );
};

// Exports
export default ButtonPaper;
```

Also, the `children` prop in `Button` component of `react-native-paper` is mandatory. So, to avoid typescript warning, you can do

```js
export type CustomButtonProps = {
  title: string;
} & Omit<React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>, "children">;
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/buttonpaper)

Comment: just wanna add that typescript auto-complete wouldn't work with

type CustomButtonProps = {
  title: string;
} & Omit<typeof Button, "children">;

,better to use 

type CustomButtonProps = {
  title: string;
} & Omit<React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>, 'children'>;